# Angular component won't react to property changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I got a header-comp, a service and a content-comp. In the header-comp I toggle a bool-var in the service to show or hide a mobile-menu (responsive).

I want to listen to this bool changes from the content-comp and it works but only if I trigger it in the service constructor:

```
  export class AppService {

  public mblMenuVisible: boolean = false;
  public mobileLayout: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.determineLayout();

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.mblMenuVisible = true;
    }, 3000);
  }

  toggleMblMenu() {
    if (this.mblMenuVisible) {
      this.mblMenuVisible = false;
    } else {
      this.mblMenuVisible = true;
    }
  }
```

if I toggle it manually via toggleMblMenu(), my content-comp won't react to this changes. ngClass in content-comp should react to this changes:

```
<div [ngClass]="(service.mblMenuVisible===true)?'mbl-content-wrapper':'content-wrapper'">
```

EDIT:

I tried:

- changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
- markForCheck()
- via Subject which only works in the header.
- Dependecies are also up to date

HEADER:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from "../shared/appService";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  private mobileMenuVisible: boolean;

  constructor(private service: AppService,
              private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.layoutAction.subscribe(
      (visible: boolean) => {
        this.mobileMenuVisible = visible;
      });
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) resize(e) {
    this.service.determineLayout();
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    if (!this.service.mobileLayout) {
      this.service.mblMenuVisible = false;
    }
  }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  public layoutAction = new Subject<boolean>();
  public mblMenuVisible: boolean = false;
  public mobileLayout: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.determineLayout();
  }
  //LAYOUT
  determineLayout() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
      this.mobileLayout = false
    } else {
      this.mobileLayout = true;
    }
  }

  toggleMblMenu (){
    this.mblMenuVisible = !this.mblMenuVisible;
    this.layoutAction.next(this.mblMenuVisible);
  }
}
```

CONTENT:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from "../shared/appService";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css'],
  providers: [ AppService ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  private mobileMenuVisible: boolean;

  constructor(private service: AppService,
              private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.service.layoutAction.subscribe(
        (visible: boolean) => {
          alert(visible);
          this.mobileMenuVisible = visible;
          this.cd.markForCheck();
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code from your components.

Comment: you just need to make `AppService ` a singleton service check my answer 

Comment: @malbarmawi i solved it with a subservice of appService. thx

Comment: @NeoGER89 you just create a singleton service and inject this one in the app service this doesn't look a good design m do you consider that app Service will keep creating multiple time for no reason

Comment: what about the appService is shared `    import {AppService} from "../shared/appService";`

Comment: check this demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-singleton-service-example 

Comment: Hi @NeoGER89 if any answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file you should bind to `mblMenuVisible` not to `service.mblMenuVisible` because in  `toggleMblMenu` method, you are changing the state of `mblMenuVisible` not of `service.mblMenuVisible`

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Using [Angular FlexLayout Responsive Features](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API#responsive-features) is a very good toolbox for this mobile problem.

New response,
now looking at this piece of code you added in your recent edit,

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  ...
  determineLayout() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
      this.mobileLayout = false
    } else {
      this.mobileLayout = true;
    }
  }
  ...
}

@Component()
export class AppComponent{
  constructor(private service:AppService){}
  ...
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) 
  resize(e) {
    this.service.determineLayout();
    //this.cd.detectChanges();
    if (!this.service.mobileLayout) {
      this.service.mblMenuVisible = false;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

---

This need can be fullfiled with the [Angular FlexLayout Responsive Features](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API#responsive-features)

after [setting up](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout#getting-started) your angular project with Angular flex,
One can write response directives like this example,

```
<div fxShow.lt-md fxHide fxFlex >
  <!-- MobileMenu Contents -->
</div>
<div fxShow fxHide.lt-md fxFlex >
  <!-- DesktopMenu Contents -->
</div>
```

[Angular FlexLayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) responsive directives are made for what you are doing here, no need to manualy listen to window resize events and trigger a boolean value changes to get your components to respond to media query breakpoints.

Moreover, there is a pure css way to achieve this with [vanilla mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Hi Simplicity's_Strength the problem is pretty simple just create singleton service this why he has a same reference and any change on the service will reflect to other component check my answer 

Comment: I agree with your answer, yet i believe OP's need could be fullfiled in a more synthetic, more accurate, more maintainable way with the options in added above.

Comment: ok I got your advice about flex layout  but the main problem is I have two component and I need to pass to them a single instance of the service so change the value in one component will effect the other 

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-singleton-service-example 

Answer (score 0):

simply your service need to be a global service for all components ,just add this `AppService`  to AppModule providers list and remove `providers: [ AppService ],` from component decorator because this way you create **two different object not one** and change te value on sigle on will not reflect the other but when you add the service to appModule will **create only once** and now you will have the same reference in all component

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
AppService  {
 ...
}
```

> [Singleton services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) A singleton service is a service for which
>   only once instance exists in an app.

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-singleton-service-example)

in the demo tow component (a , b) change the value of the property `mblMenuVisible` and thired component has inject this service and react to the change of the value to show or hide an example component called menu , the main reason of the value is change becuase the injected `AppService` is the same object